# How can I write a query to get the result I want?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I could use some help writing an IIF statement in a query. I have done a lot of research on IIF statements and know their basic syntax and structure. But all of the examples I could find on the internet were very basic and pretty straight forward, and I need mine to be a little more complex.

I have two tables in MS Access 2010. One is called "ProductMasterData" and the other is "DateCodes." Every record in the ProductMasterData table has a field  called "CartonDateFormat" that contains a number 1-36. Every record in the DateCodes table has a field called "OutputDateCode." What I would like for my IIF statement to say is that if CartonDateCode= 1, then return the OutputDateCode from row 1. If CartonDateCode is not equal to 1, then do nothing. I want to write similar IIF statements that will do the same thing for numbers 2-36. I have an idea of what the statements should look like, but it's fuzzy and I could use a little help. I am thinking that it should look something like this:

```
IIF(CartonDateFormat=1, I don't know what to put here, Nothing)
```

I'm not sure how to phrase what to do if the first part of the statement equates to true. This is my first query, so I would really appreciate any help anyone could give me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs maybe you should better join the 2 tables.
If you just need these `IIF()` statements you can do this:

```
IIF(
  CartonDateFormat = 1, 
  (SELECT OutputDateCode FROM DateCodes WHERE ID = 1), 
  NULL
)
```

I assume there is a column like `ID` in the table `DateCodes` which stores these codes that the values in `CartonDateFormat` correspond to.
But even without `IIF()` if you simply use:

```
SELECT OutputDateCode FROM DateCodes WHERE ID = 1
```

the result will be the same: 
-If the id is found then the `OutputDateCode` will be returned. 
-If not then NULL will be returned.